# Why do my particles appear darker the farther I get from them?

Tags: particles, unreal-4, clouds

I've created the following material:

[image]

I've set up a particle system that places that material around like a cloud:

[image]

Up close, I'm getting the result I expect:

[image]

But if I go far enough, it looks like this:

[image]

Why do these dark areas appear and why are they more pronounced as I look at them from farther and farther away?

I know I can make this go away by increasing environment lighting or making the material more emissive. Do I have more options beyond these two?

Comment: Haven't used Unreal engine, but 2 guesses are Antialiasing or Mipmaps gone wrong. You should be able to test either by disabling them.